# How to find a specific path in a VectorDrawable?

Tags: android, drawable

I'm trying to dynamically set a background color on two specific path of a SVG (VectorDrawable). But can't find a way to get them from my view. I added ID's to those paths but I'm not aware of any method I can use to get them.

Here is some code to explain my issue :

```
<vector android:height="150dp" android:viewportHeight="24"
    android:viewportWidth="24" android:width="150dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:id="@+id/backgroundFirst" android:name="background_first" android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="m12,0c-6.617,0 -12,5.383 -12,12s5.383,12 12,12 12,-5.383 12,-12 -5.383,-12 -12,-12z"/>
    <path android:id="@+id/backgroundSecond" android:name="background_second" android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="m12,0c-6.617,0 -12,5.383 -12,12s5.383,12 12,12z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#fff" android:pathData="m12,18.25v-3.25h-5.75c-0.689,0 -1.25,-0.561 -1.25,-1.25v-3.5c0,-0.689 0.561,-1.25 1.25,-1.25h5.75v-3.25c0,-0.66 0.795,-0.999 1.27,-0.541l6.5,6.25c0.147,0.142 0.23,0.337 0.23,0.541s-0.083,0.399 -0.23,0.541l-6.5,6.25c-0.475,0.456 -1.27,0.12 -1.27,-0.541z"/>
    <path android:fillColor="#dedede" android:pathData="m5,12h15c0,0.204 -0.083,0.399 -0.23,0.541l-6.5,6.25c-0.15,0.144 -0.334,0.209 -0.514,0.209 -0.385,0 -0.756,-0.298 -0.756,-0.75v-3.25h-5.75c-0.689,0 -1.25,-0.561 -1.25,-1.25z"/>
</vector>
```

As you can see, the first two paths have an ID I would like to use to get them. Here is what I'm trying to do in my view :

```
VectorDrawable nextIcon = (VectorDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_next); 

// Here I get my drawable as a VectorDrawable
// From there I want to access the specific paths and set a background or backgroundColor.
```